# xts dropping column names

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have a data.frame

```
res0 = structure(list(year = "2017", il = 11200000), .Names = c("year", 
"il"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

however, when I try to make this an xts object I lose the column names.

```
as.xts(x = res0[,2:ncol(res0)], order.by = as.POSIXct(paste0(res0$year,"-01-01")), name = NULL)
```

This returns:

```
               [,1]
2017-01-01 11200000
```

instead of

```
                 il
2017-01-01 11200000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscripting in R drops dimensions by default.  Use `drop = FALSE` to prevent this.

```
res0[, 2:ncol(res0), drop = FALSE]
```

Also note that this works to create an n x 1 zoo series with year as the index.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(res0, FUN = c, drop = FALSE)
```